# How do I redirect a user to a new page using url containing Id in nextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm new nextJs & I need help creating an URL for redirecting to a detail page that includes a id as part of the URL after an onclick event is triggered, below is my code

```
Import {Router} from 'next'
const router = Router
const redirect =(id)=>{
    const url = `/hello/${id}/world`
    router.push(url)
}


render(
  <button onClick={(element)=>. 
     {redirect(element.id)}}></button>

)
```

I've created the page with the exact name hello-world and I'm expecting that when the button is clicked, the user should be redirected to a hello/id/world page, but instead a 404 page not found error is returned

Comment: is the hello world page dynamic? Secondly please post your file configuration structure..like how your app layout looks like

Comment: What's the URL that you get when you click the button?

Comment: Yea it meant to be dynamic since the id changes @RobinMuhia254

Comment: @technophyle I'm getting the correct url when the button is clicked,   the problem is instead of displaying the hello world part, it displays a 404 errors

Comment: You need to define the route in the first place in order to show any content in that route. Did you do that?